# Why isn't there an option to upsert data in Azure Data Factory inline sink

Tags: azure-sql-database, azure-pipelines, azure-data-factory

The problem I'm trying to tackle is inserting and/or updating dynamic tables in a sink within an Azure Data Factory data flow. I've managed to get the source data, transform it how I want it and then send it to a sink. The pipeline ran successfully and it said it copied 37 rows (as expected) but investigation showed that no data was actually deposited in the target table. This was because the Table Action on the sink was set to 'None'. So in trying to fix this last part, it seems I don't have the 'Create' option but do have the 'Recreate' option (see screenshot of the sink below) which is not what I want as the datasource will eventually only have changed data. I need the process to create the table if it doesn't exist and then Upsert data. (Recreate drops the table and then creates it).
If I change the sink type from Inline to Dataset, then I can select Insert and Upsert, etc options but this is then not dynamic as I need to select a specific dataset.
So has anyone come across the same issue and have you managed to have dynamic sinks in your data flow where the table is created if it doesn't exist, then upsert data.
I guess I can add a Pre SQL script which takes care of the 'create the table if it doesn't exist' but I still can't select the Upsert option with inline tables.
[image: Screenshot showing inline table options]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS issue, I would recommend a Stored Procedure that is executed in the pipeline prior to the Data Flow.

For Inline vs Dataset, you can make the Dataset very flexible:

[image]

[image]

[image]

So still based on your runtime table name and no schema, so no need to target a specific table.

For the UPSERT issue, make sure you have an AlterRow activity before the Sink:
[image]

Comment: Thanks Joel for the quick and detailed reply. I've got the stored procedure in the PreSql to create the table if it doesn't exist and I do have the AlterRow activity just before the sink. My test pipeline runs successfully and reports 37 rows but still, no actual data is copied into the target table. Although I now have the Insert and Upsert update methods selected, the Table options are still None, Recreate table and Truncate table and I suspect I have no data written as the selection I've got is None. I'll test with the Recreate option.

Comment: Not sure what is going on there, but "None" should be correct.

Comment: Hi Joel. Yes, I've managed to get it working. The 'None' option was correct. Thanks for your help.